# Code Coverage for Visual Studio 2017 Community with C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, code-coverage

Are there any plugins for visual studio 2017 which enable to calculate unit test code coverage with C++?

I only found 
OpenCppCoverage:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OpenCppCoverage.OpenCppCoveragePlugin

but it seems to be outdated / not working.

Other than that it seems like there are only Code coverage plugins for .Net-Languages but not C++

Are there any other options (besides upgrading to MSVC Enterprise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently tested [CPPCoverage](https://github.com/atlaste/CPPCoverage), an open source and free extension that works perfectly to perform code coverage of native Visual C++ unit tests.

It is a visual extension (VSIX) and provide details reports. Once installed, Right-click in solution explorer on the test or application project and click "Run code coverage".

Comment: CPPCoverage depends on Visual Studio 2015 shell unfortunately (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0). OpenCppCoverage is working for me. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OpenCppCoverage.OpenCppCoveragePlugin